# how to calculate the dictionary average for each cycle when dictionary has the same dictionary name in for cycle

Tags: python

I meet a problem.
I write a for the cycle, and want to calculate the dictionary average for each cycle, how to do it in python? Thanks advanced!

```
    for i in range(len(oneImageTest)):
        m = 0
            for j in range(y):
                for k in range(x):
                    d={}
                    m=m+1
                    d[class_name1] = predict1
                    d[class_name2] = predict2
                    ...
                    print(i, d)
```

the print results for example:

```
0 {'U7090Z_W_E': 0.99, 'U5176B_W_E': 0.98, 'U3820B_W_E': 0.97, '7088B_W_E_0': 0.93, '5498B_C_E_1': 0.98}
1 {'U7090Z_W_E': 0.97, 'U5176B_W_E': 0.94, 'U3820B_W_E': 0.98, '7088B_W_E_0': 0.96}
2 {'U7090Z_W_E': 0.95, 'U3820B_W_E': 0.94, '7088B_W_E_0': 0.93}
```

I want to get the result:

```
{'U7090Z_W_E': 0.97, 'U5176B_W_E': 0.96, 'U3820B_W_E': 0.96, '7088B_W_E_0': 0.94, '5498B_C_E_1': 0.98}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append the values in a new dict:

```
for i in mydict:
     for key, value in i.items():
         newdict[key]=newdict.get(key,[])
         newdict[key].append(value)
```

then calculate the average:

```
for key, value in newdict.items():
     print(f"{key} average: {sum(value)/len(value)}")
```

I tested with your sample data:

```
mydict = [{'U7090Z_W_E': 0.99, 'U5176B_W_E': 0.98, 'U3820B_W_E': 0.97, '7088B_W_E_0': 0.93, '5498B_C_E_1': 0.98},
{'U7090Z_W_E': 0.97, 'U5176B_W_E': 0.94, 'U3820B_W_E': 0.98, '7088B_W_E_0': 0.96},
{'U7090Z_W_E': 0.95, 'U3820B_W_E': 0.94, '7088B_W_E_0': 0.93}]
newdict = {}
for i in mydict:
    for key, value in i.items():
        newdict[key]=newdict.get(key,[])
        newdict[key].append(value)

for key, value in newdict.items():
    print(f"{key} average: {sum(value)/len(value)}")

U7090Z_W_E average: 0.9700000000000001
U5176B_W_E average: 0.96
U3820B_W_E average: 0.9633333333333333
7088B_W_E_0 average: 0.9400000000000001
5498B_C_E_1 average: 0.98
```

Comment: Got the error when I test your code @Bendik
{'U7090Z_W_E': 0.9991779, 'U5176B_W_E': 0.9423827, 'U3820B_W_E': 0.9673023, '7088B_W_E_0': 0.95713603, '5498B_C_E_1': 0.9815778}

<class 'dict'>

AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-45-8ea7145de90d> in <module>()
    111             print(type(d)) #dictory
    112             for n in d:
--> 113                 for key,value in n.items():
    114                     newDict[key]=newDict.get(key,[])
    115                     newDict[key].append(value)


AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'. But I print the d, it shows me the <class 'dict'> type.

Comment: sorry i missed a line ill clean it up